# How to fix my unresponsive remove div function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

My code works perfectly in codepen (link below) but for some reason in the browser it's not working. I am running the code from localhost and the button just isn't responding.

[CODE](https://codepen.io/dnorton94/pen/abowxgx)

Here is my VS code

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.removeDiv').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('#cookieNotice').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Font Awesome CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.min.css">

  <!-- Index Javascript-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>

  <title>Urabiliti Home Page</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="page-footer font-small blue fixed-bottom bg-light" id="cookieNotice">

    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">This website uses
      <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/"> cookies</a> to ensure you get the best experience on our website
    </div>

    <!-- remove cookie notice -->
    <div class="removeDiv text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-4">Got it</button>
    </div>
    <!-- remove cookie notice -->
    <!-- Copyright -->

  </footer>
  <!-- Footer -->

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

I expect the div to be removed onclick

Comment: what errors do you see in the browser developer console - my guess is your index.js in the head is trying to use jquery before it is loaded at the end of the file

Comment: by the way ... codepen runs in the browser ... so saying it works on codepen but not in the browser makes no sense at all

Comment: @JaromandaX that statement makes no sense but do you understand the question?

When I use the code snippet it works. When I run from my local directory it doesn't.

No errors shows. It doesn't even pick up a request is being made.

Comment: Did you check the browser developer tools console like I suggested on the first comment rather than concentrating on my second comment? Your code is running before jquery is loaded. Common rookie mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are facing this issue as you are adding the `<script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>` before the jQuery script. Moving it to the end of the page should solve the issue.

The execution of the JavaScript happens in sequential order. In this case, first, the contents of the index.js will be executed and then jQuery.

When a script contains dependencies on another script, then order in which they are included makes difference. They should be included in the order of their dependencies.